Polars: read_parquet with how='diagonal'
Is there a way to do the same as the "how" parameter from pl.concat but with read_parquet?

It has been requested a few times, nothing has been added as of yet. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12508

I don't think you can do it via standard read_parquet(), but you can concat dataframes created from different files:
import glob
import polars as pl

df_d1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [3]})
df_d2 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [2], "c": [4]})

df_d1.write_parquet("df1.parquet")
df_d2.write_parquet("df2.parquet")

pl.concat(
    (pl.scan_parquet(f) for f in glob.glob("df*.parquet")),
    how="diagonal"
).collect()

┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ 4    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘


If you are OK using pyarrow (use_pyarrow=True), you can:

collect the schemas from the metadata with pq.read_schema,
merge them into one with pa.unify_schemas, and
add the schema via pyarrow_options inside pl.read_parquet:

import polars as pl
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import glob

df_d1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [3]})
df_d2 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [2], "c": [4]})

df_d1.write_parquet('df_d1.parquet')
df_d2.write_parquet('df_d2.parquet')

source = glob.glob("df*.parquet")
schema = pa.unify_schemas((pq.read_schema(f) for f in source))

df = pl.read_parquet(source=source, use_pyarrow=True, 
                     pyarrow_options={'schema': schema})

Result
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ 4    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘

